# How to use request.META.HTTP_HOST inside Django models?

Tags: django, python-3.x, http, request

I'm trying to improve my app's SEO by having absolute URLs to my links (link for each world city).

I managed to do so in the template by doing this:

```
<a title="{{city.name}}" href="http://{{ request.META.HTTP_HOST }}/{{city.get_absolute_url}} " target="_blank">{{ city.name }} </a>
```

However I'm trying to implement the same from the model in a way that I can simply do this:

```
<a title="{{city.name}}" href="{{city.get_absolute_url}} " target="_blank">{{ city.name }} </a>
```

This is my attempt:

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "http://" + self.request.META.HTTP_HOST + '/city/%s/' % self.slug
```

But I get this:

```
name 'request' is not defined
```

How can I import the user request to use in a model?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do using HTTP_HOST - you realise a client can send whatever it wants as that, right? (Also not seeing how it improves see)

Comment: Also it's not clear why having an absolute link would improve your SEO.

Comment: I'm trying to have absolute urls instead of relative ones. So: Http://www.example.com/city/london to be inside href instead of /city/london @JonClements

Comment: I received this recommendation from SEO expert. Also links on SO are absolute. @DanielRoseman

Comment: Having `/city/london` is absolutely fine... having `london` when you're on `/city` is not (the city page should refer to `/city/london`)... I think you're confusing things here... you really don't want the scheme and domain in there...  That's my thoughts anyway - not sure if @Daniel agrees or not...

Comment: SO links aren't absolute, the list of questions has `href="/questions/46704748/how-to-use-request-meta-http-host-inside-django-models"` for your own question. You shouldn't add the protocol and domain name to your links, it doesn't matter for SEO.

Comment: replace `href="http://{{ request.META.HTTP_HOST }}` with `href="{{ request.scheme }}://{{ request.META.HTTP_HOST }}`